# How do these two integration by parts formulas relate to one another?

Tags: calculus

So I want to write a book about indefinite integration and I am using some textbooks and some websites for some theorems and I found in one textbook this formula for indefinite integration by parts. $$\int \frac{d}{dx} \Big( f \left( x \right) \Big) g \left( x \right) dx = f \left( x \right) g \left( x \right) - \int f \left( x \right) \frac{d}{dx} \Big( g \left( x \right) \Big) dx$$ I included it in my book but I know that this formula: $$\int udv =uv - \int vdu$$ exists and I want to include this one as well. However I don't know what substitutions I need to link them together. Can anyone help me with the u, v, du, dv and what they correspond with in the bigger formula?

Comment: They are literally the same thing but with different notation. The second one avoids writing the variable explicitly.

Comment: The first is a particular case of the second, if you put $u=g$ and $v=f$, for some differentiable functions $f$ and $g$. In this case, $dv=df=\frac{df}{dx}(x)dx$ and $du=dg=\frac{dg}{dx}(x)dx$. The second can be used in [a bit more general situations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties).